# How do I combine two lists in Dart?

Tags: list, generics, dart, concatenation

I was wondering if there was an easy way to concatenate two lists in dart to create a brand new list object. I couldn't find anything and something like this:

My list:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [4, 5, 6]
```

I tried:

```
var newList = list1 + list2;
```

I wanted the combined output of:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 472, accepted):

You can use:

```dart
var newList = new List.from(list1)..addAll(list2);
```

If you have several lists you can use:

```dart
var newList = [list1, list2, list3].expand((x) => x).toList()
```

As of Dart 2 you can now use `+`:

```
var newList = list1 + list2 + list3;
```

As of Dart 2.3 you can use the spread operator:

```
var newList = [...list1, ...list2, ...list3];
```

Comment: An alternative (which allows to easily concatenate many lists): `[list1, list2, list3, ...].expand((x) => x).toList()`;

Comment: Note that the `+`  operator cannot be be used on lists of different types. (in this case you get an error like `type 'List<Widget>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Image>'`. ). The spread operator works great for this use case though.

Comment: Can you please check this question and suggest me something. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62228799/flutter-merge-one-list-data-to-another-list#62228799

Comment: And  what about performance? No answer is talking about that...

Answer (score 25):

Dart now [supports](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.1/dart-core/List/operator_plus.html) concatenation of lists using the `+` operator.

Example:

```
List<int> result = [0, 1, 2] + [3, 4, 5];
```

Comment: This is the most up-to-date answer

Answer (score 21):

maybe more consistent~

```dart
var list = []..addAll(list1)..addAll(list2);
```

Comment: Old i know but what is the `..addAll()` why not just a single dot?

Comment: @Abbas.M .. is for chaining, to do with out the double dot you would have to:
list = []; list.addAll(list1); list.addAll(list2);  The way I see it, it basically means call this function, but ignore what it returns, and keep operating on the object we were operating on.

Answer (score 20):

If you want to merge two lists and remove duplicates, you convert your final list to a `Set` using `{}` :

```
var newList = {...list1, ...list2}.toList();
```

Comment: `var newList = {...list1, ...list2}.toList();`

Answer (score 10):

Alexandres' answer is the best but if you wanted to use + like in your example you can use Darts operator overloading:

```dart
class MyList<T>{
  List<T> _internal = new List<T>();
  operator +(other) => new List<T>.from(_internal)..addAll(other);
  noSuchMethod(inv){
    //pass all calls to _internal
  }
}
```

Then:

```dart
var newMyList = myList1 + myList2;
```

Is valid :)

Answer (score 7):

I collect all possible method and benchmark it using benchmark_harness package.

According to the result the recommended method is:

- `final List<int> c = a + b;`
- `final List<int> c = [...a, ...b];`

Here is the benchmark code:

```
import 'package:benchmark_harness/benchmark_harness.dart';

List<int> a = [1, 2, 3];
List<int> b = [4, 5, 6];

class Benchmark1 extends BenchmarkBase {
  const Benchmark1() : super('c = a + b ');

  @override
  void run() {
    final List<int> c = a + b;
  }
}

class Benchmark2 extends BenchmarkBase {
  const Benchmark2() : super('c = a.followedBy(b).toList() ');

  @override
  void run() {
    final List<int> c = a.followedBy(b).toList();
  }
}

class Benchmark3 extends BenchmarkBase {
  const Benchmark3() : super('c = [a, b].expand((x) => x).toList() ');

  @override
  void run() {
    final List<int> c = [a, b].expand((x) => x).toList();
  }
}

class Benchmark4 extends BenchmarkBase {
  const Benchmark4() : super('c = [a, b].reduce((value, element) => value + element) ');

  @override
  void run() {
    final List<int> c = [a, b].reduce((value, element) => value + element);
  }
}

class Benchmark5 extends BenchmarkBase {
  const Benchmark5() : super('c = [a, b].fold([], (previousValue, element) => previousValue + element) ');

  @override
  void run() {
    final List<int> c = [a, b].fold([], (previousValue, element) => previousValue + element);
  }
}

class Benchmark6 extends BenchmarkBase {
  const Benchmark6() : super('a.addAll(b) ');

  @override
  void run() {
    a.addAll(b);
  }
}

class Benchmark7 extends BenchmarkBase {
  const Benchmark7() : super('c = <int>[...a, ...b] ');

  @override
  void run() {
    final List<int> c = <int>[...a, ...b];
  }
}

class Benchmark8 extends BenchmarkBase {
  const Benchmark8() : super('c = List.from(a)..addAll(b) ');

  @override
  void run() {
    final List<int> c = List.from(a)..addAll(b);
  }
}

void main() {
  // Benchmark1().report();
  // Benchmark2().report();
  // Benchmark3().report();
  // Benchmark4().report();
  // Benchmark5().report();
  // Benchmark6().report();
  // Benchmark7().report();
  Benchmark8().report();
}
```

And the result:

```
c = a + b (RunTime): 0.8384643860155879 us.
c = a.followedBy(b).toList() (RunTime): 1.3018350015264015 us.
c = [a, b].expand((x) => x).toList() (RunTime): 2.194391139053011 us.
c = [a, b].reduce((value, element) => value + element) (RunTime): 1.1215188056273329 us.
c = [a, b].fold([], (previousValue, element) => previousValue + element) (RunTime): 1.7163271628511283 us.
a.addAll(b) (RunTime): 1.08603684815237 us.
c = <int>[...a, ...b] (RunTime): 0.8498483658053312 us.
c = List.from(a)..addAll(b) (RunTime): 0.9107294347150762 us.
```

Answer (score 5):

If one of your list is nullable, use `...?` operator:

```dart
var newList = [
  ...?list1,
  ...?list2,
  ...?list3,
];
```

If you also want to remove duplicate items in the list:

```dart
var newList = {
  ...?list1,
  ...?list2,
  ...?list3,
}.toList();
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is another one:

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

final x = [1, 2, 3];
final y = [4, 5, 6];
final z = [x, y].flattened // Iterable<int>
final result = z.toList();
```

Note that `flattened` is defined as extension on `Iterable<Iterable<T>>` and hence also works with other iterables.

Comment: this one comes from collection package which is now a part of Flutter SDK so do not  forget to `import 'package:collection/collection.dart';`

Answer (score 3):

No need to create a third list in my opinion...

Use this:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3];
list2 = [4, 5, 6];
list1.addAll(list2);

print(list1); 
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] // is our final result!
```

Answer (score 3):

`addAll` is the most common way to merge two lists.

But to concatenate list of lists, you can use any of these three functions (examples below):

- [expand](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/Iterable/expand.html) - Expands each element of an Iterable into zero or more elements,
- [fold](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/Iterable/fold.html) - Reduces a collection to a single value by iteratively combining each element of the collection *with an existing value*,
- [reduce](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/Iterable/reduce.html) - Reduces a collection to a single value by iteratively combining elements of the collection *using the provided function*.

```
void main() {
  List<int> a = [1,2,3];
  List<int> b = [4,5];
  List<int> c = [6];
  List<List<int>> abc = [a,b,c]; // list of lists: [ [1,2,3], [4,5], [6] ]
  List<int> ints = abc.expand((x) => x).toList();
  List<int> ints2 = abc.reduce((list1,list2) => list1 + list2);
  List<int> ints3 = abc.fold([], (prev, curr) => prev + curr); // initial value is []
  print(ints);  // [1,2,3,4,5,6]
  print(ints2); // [1,2,3,4,5,6]
  print(ints3); // [1,2,3,4,5,6]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For Dart 2.3+ & the people from **JavaScript** community:

```
var mergedList = [...listX, ...listY, ...listZ].toSet();
```

`toSet()` will filter and return only unique items.

Answer (score 1):

```
 list1.followedBy(list2).toList();
```

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Answer (score 1):

> Method 1 -> By using the `addAll()` function

```
var array1 = [1, 2, 3];
var array2 = [4, 5, 6];
array1.addAll(array2); // array1 is now [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

> Method 2 -> By using the `loop`.

```
var array1 = [1, 2, 3];
var array2 = [4, 5, 6];
array2.forEach((item) {
   array1.add(item);
}); // array1 is now [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

> Method 3 -> By using the `+` operator.

```
var array1 = [1, 2, 3];
var array1 = [4, 5, 6];
var newArray = array1 + array1;  // array1 is now [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

One note about performance. Keep in mind that all utilizing all those "reduce" methods will create another list for each operation.

So the most performant way (especially for bigger list of lists) will always be "old good C-style":

```
List<T> concatLists<T>(List<List<T>> listOfLists, [bool isGrowable = true]) {
  if (listOfLists.first.isEmpty) {
    throw Exception('first list of lists cannot be empty');
  }

  int totalLength = 0;
  for (final list in listOfLists) {
    totalLength += list.length;
  }

  List<T> result =
      List<T>.filled(totalLength, listOfLists[0][0], growable: isGrowable);
  int idx = 0;
  for (final list in listOfLists) {
    for (final item in list) {
      result[idx] = item;
      idx += 1;
    }
      // result.addAll(list); // at least 2x longer
  }

  return result;
}
```

Sure I like to write that syntax sugar too, like [...list1, ...list2], but for larger portions of data you need something more optimized. For example, for converting 50mb data-bytes which is stored in a `List<List<int>>` into one `List<int>`.

This approach is at least 2x faster when compared to other approaches. I tested `list1 + list2` and `listOfLists.reduce(...)` .