# Flutter: Merge one List data to another list

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting the data from a database using an Http request.

```
 List<String> options = [
      'News', 'Entertainment', 'Politics',
      'Automotive', 'Sports', 'Education',
      'Fashion', 'Travel', 'Food', 'Tech',
      'Science',
    ];
```

I need to merge this data to the List as below format.

```
class Language extends Taggable {
  final String name;

  /// Creates Language
  Language({
    this.name,
  });

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [name];

  /// Converts the class to json string.
  String toJson() => '''  {
    "name": $name,\n

  }''';  
}

 <Language>[
      Language(name: 'JavaScript'),
      Language(name: 'Python'),
      Language(name: 'Java'),
      Language(name: 'PHP'),
      Language(name: 'C#'),
      Language(name: 'C++'),
    ]
        .where((lang) => lang.name.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()))
        .toList();
```

Any advise.

**Edit:**

I have tried these two codes but still getting the error.

```
var languages = options.map((el) => Language(name: el));
---->  No error but options list data not added/merged in Language(name).

    var a = options.expand((el) => Language(name: el));
--------> The return type 'Language' isn't a 'Iterable<_>', as required by the closure's context.
```

Comment: it's not clear about format do you need to make a list of Languages from the list of strings?  `var languages = options.map((el) => Language(name: el));`

Comment: @Kherel I basically want to use option List to Language class.

Comment: @Kherel I tried your suggestion but Language is not containing the list items those are part of Options list.