# Is there anyway I can add a List of the same class together in flutter because it seem the inport is giving issue s

Tags: flutter

[Var favourite=[... upcoming,... trending,... popular]
The result is and import of upcoming so I am having issues with trending and popular
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhOLR.jpg)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21826342/how-do-i-combine-two-lists-in-dart

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of errors/code when posting a question.  See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question.