# combine lists in one list in flutter dart

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I have 100 sample of data coming from microcontroller via bluetooth in a form of Uint8List continuously. The data is coming through bluetooth buffer and I am using flutter bluetooth serial package to receive data via bluetooth.
The data is arriving in this form:

```
[115, 43, 48, 46, 56, 54, 101, 0, 0, 115]
[43, 49, 46, 55, 49, 101, 0, 0, 115, 43]
[0, 0, 115, 43, 51, 46, 53, 57, 101, 0, 0, 115, 43, 51, 46] ... ect

(note that this is just an example of the result and the completed result is about 80 lists of Uint all coming to the same var which is data)
```

The size of the List containing the Uint is not consistent. So I want to combine all these coming data in one List.

This is the code I am trying to use which is not working as the data is not being combined.

```
connection!.input!.listen(_onDataReceived).onDone(() {
        if (isDisconnecting) {
          print('Disconnecting locally!');
        } else {
          print('Disconnected remotely!');
        }
        if (this.mounted) {
          setState(() {});
        }
      }


 Future<void> _onDataReceived(  Uint8List data ) async {

    List newLst =[];
    newLst.add(data);
    int i = 0;
    Queue stack = new Queue();
    stack.addAll(newLst);


    print(data);
    print(stack);



  }
```

How can I combine all the coming data in one big list and store it for later operations.

Comment: which output do you want?

Comment: what does not work with `List.addAll`?

Comment: I want to print the combined version of the list

Comment: List.addAll didnt do the job as every time new data arrives, it overwrite the old one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I combine two lists in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21826342/how-do-i-combine-two-lists-in-dart)

Comment: I think the question was not very clear please read the updated question in a min

Comment: check how you can use `Stream.expand` method: `connection!.input!.expand((data) => data).listen(print)` or `final data = await connection!.input!.expand((data) => data).toList()`

Comment: I got this error: Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.

Comment: because you cannot use `toList()` and `listen()` the same stream - check `toList` [implementation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/toList.html)

Comment: even if i dont use listen(), I get another error Unexpected text 'await'. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> note that this is just an example of the result and the completed result is about 80 lists of Uint all coming to the same var which is data

**If I'm not wrong**, `connection!.input` is a [`Stream`](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams).

If so, then seems your problem isn't about lists as you said, but about `Stream`s.

Since you are listening to a `Stream`:

```dart
connection!.input!.listen(_onDataReceived).onDone(...);
```

And you want to **alter, modify or process the upcoming data from a `Stream`** then you probably want to use some of the native [`Stream`](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams) API.

In this particular case, you want to reduce all upcoming events (list of `Uint8List`) and process into a single output (a single `Uint8List` containing all data), then you can use `Stream<T>.reduce` which returns a `Future<T>` that resolves when there are no more upcoming events (`Stream` did emit the *done* event).

You don't even need to listen since you want just to process the single output not each event individually:

```dart
final Uint8List mergedData = await connection!.input!.reduce((previous, current) => Uint8List.fromList([...previous, ...current]));
```

Take [a look at this DartPad snippet](https://dartpad.dev/?id=aede3d2385918acc6dc365d84236fb3a) to see a full example.

To see full API, check out the [official Dart documentation](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams) for `Stream`s, it's complete and didactic.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
void main() {
  List l1 = [115, 43, 48, 46, 56, 54, 101, 0, 0, 115];
  List l2 = [43, 49, 46, 55, 49, 101, 0, 0, 115, 43];
  List l3 = [0, 0, 115, 43, 51, 46, 53, 57, 101, 0, 0, 115, 43, 51, 46];

  l1.addAll(l2 + l3);
  print(l1);
}
```

Output:

```
[115, 43, 48, 46, 56, 54, 101, 0, 0, 115, 43, 49, 46, 55, 49, 101, 0, 0, 115, 43, 0, 0, 115, 43, 51, 46, 53, 57, 101, 0, 0, 115, 43, 51, 46]
```

Comment: I think the question was not very clear please read the updated question in a min

Answer (score 0):

Check BytesBuilder:

```
  var combinedList = BytesBuilder();
  var l1 = Uint8List(5);
  var l2 = Uint8List(5);
  combinedList.add(l1);
  combinedList.add(l2);
  var combinedList_to_Uint8List = combinedList.toBytes()
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that your data will not overflow your memory when stored all in one. If OK, look:

```
List<T> concatLists<T>(List<List<T>> listOfLists, [bool isGrowable = true]) {
  if (listOfLists.first.isEmpty) {
    throw Exception('first list of lists cannot be empty');
  }

  int totalLength = 0;
  for (final list in listOfLists) {
    totalLength += list.length;
  }

  List<T> result =
      List<T>.filled(totalLength, listOfLists[0][0], growable: isGrowable);
  int idx = 0;
  for (final list in listOfLists) {
    for (final item in list) {
      result[idx] = item;
      idx += 1;
    }
      // result.addAll(list); // at least 2x longer
  }

  return result;
}
```

This is the most performant way I know. Just store this function somewhere inside your metaphorical "utils_and_helpers" folder and utilize when needed.