# How can i add an entire list on top of another list in Flutter

Tags: dart

AddAll is pretty cool, but adds it at the bottom of the list.

I want to add the sorted list A on top of the sorted list B. I need list A for a different view

```dart
listA = [1, 2, 3];
listB = [4, 5, 6];

listB.addAll(listA);
// lista == [4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]
```

The easiest but maybe bad solution i can think of is to add first listA then listB to a listC.

```dart
listC = [];
listC.addAll(listA);
listC.addAll(listB);
//listc == [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
listB = []
listB.addAll(listC)
// garbage collector to gets rid of C
// listB == [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
// listA == [1, 2, 3];
```

This seems a bit inefficient, so I was wondering if there is a better way for this that doesn't include loops or anything thelike. Something like flutters 'addAt', like `listB.addAllAt(0, listA)`

To clarify, having a third list is a 'necessary evil' that i would like to avoid. I want one list that would be AB, and one list that is just A, to go back to the question, how do i add A on top of B.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I combine two lists in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21826342/how-do-i-combine-two-lists-in-dart)

Answer (score 0):

While the suggest answer did not solve my issue, it gave me the right idea. I can add them with 'plus' into one of the original lists

```dart
listA = [1, 2, 3];
listB = [4, 5, 6];

listB = listA+listB;

// listB == [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
// listA == [1, 2, 3];
```

Thank you MendelG for the right idea!